# How to correctly test React with act

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing

I'm trying to test a component but it errors with

```
console.error
    Warning: An update to Example inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).
    
    When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):
    
    act(() => {
      /* fire events that update state */
    });
    /* assert on the output */
    
    This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user would see in the browser. Learn more at https://reactjs.org/link/wrap-tests-with-act
        at Example (/Users/thr15/Developmemt/Boost/basket-creator/frontend/src/Page/F1/Example.tsx:5:29)
        at WrapperComponent (/Users/thr15/Developmemt/Boost/basket-creator/frontend/node_modules/enzyme-adapter-utils/src/createMountWrapper.jsx:49:26)
```

Here's a simplified version of my component

```
import {useState} from 'react';

function Example(): JSX.Element {

    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [results, setResults] = useState<number[]>([]);

    /**
     * Search the baskets.
     */
    const search = async () => {

        // Let the UI know we're loading
        setLoading(true);

        // Get the baskets
        try {
            const baskets: number[] = await (await fetch('/test?name=' + name)).json();

            // Give the UI the data
            setLoading(false);
            setResults(baskets);
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
    };

    return <div className={"content"}>
        <input value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}/>
        <button onClick={search}>Search</button>
        {results.length}
    </div>
}

export default Example;
```

and my test so far

```
import Enzyme, {mount} from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from '@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17';
import Example from "./Example";

Enzyme.configure({adapter: new Adapter()});

describe('Example', () => {
    test('searching requests the correct URL', () => {

        fetch = jest.fn(() =>
            Promise.resolve({
                json: () => Promise.resolve([{a: 1}, {b: 2}]),
            })
        );

        let searchButton;
        const wrapper = mount(<Example/>);
        const input = wrapper.find('input').at(0);
        searchButton = wrapper.find('button').at(0);

        input.simulate('change', {target: {value: 'Driver Name'}});
        searchButton.simulate('click');
        
        expect(searchButton.text()).toBe('Search');
        expect(fetch.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
        expect(fetch.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe('/test?name=Driver Name');
    });
});
```

I've tried wrapping act around various parts of the test, and it either still errors, or the name isn't appended to the query string. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

UPDATE:
Working test below for anyone (and probably me!) in the future

```
describe('Example', () => {
    test('searching requests the correct URL', async () => {

        fetch = jest.fn(() =>
            Promise.resolve({
                json: () => Promise.resolve([{a: 1}, {b: 2}]),
            })
        );

        let searchButton: ReactWrapper;
        const wrapper = mount(<Example/>);
        const input = wrapper.find('input').at(0);
        searchButton = wrapper.find('button').at(0);

        input.simulate('change', {target: {value: 'Driver Name'}});

        await act(async () => {
            searchButton.simulate('click');
        });

        expect(searchButton.text()).toBe('Search');
        expect(fetch.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
        expect(fetch.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe('/test?name=Driver Name');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that it is the clicking of the search button that is generating the act warning.

From `react@16.9.0`, `act` was changed to return a promise, meaning that you can avoid these types of warnings when testing async handlers.

Wrapping your search click simulation in an async act, might resolve the warning - but you might have to add a little timeout (not sure how this works with enzyme)

```js
await act(() => {
  searchButton.simulate('click');
})
```

Here are some more resources on the topic that might help you along the way:

- [secrets of the act(...) api](https://github.com/threepointone/react-act-examples/blob/master/sync.md)
- [React’s sync and async `act`](https://medium.com/@bmb21/reacts-sync-and-async-act-caa297b658b0)

Comment: It's not just that. It'll also be thrown when the async call finishes and updates the state. `@testing-library` has a `waitFor` that allows you to poll for the results. It doesn't appear that Enzyme is actually working on a solution for this, but there is a hacky workaround here: https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor

Comment: I'll have a look at that link above, but I did manage to get it to work, I've added the updated test to my OP